# How to get element id using v-for vuejs directive?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm a vue.js beginner, so I need help.
I write an HTML page which show a list of object in a simple table.
The table is made by a script which get a JSON object from a servlet and shows it using a v-for directive.
In each row of the table, there is a button that the user can click to book the object wrote in the corresponding row, using a form.
The problem is that I don't know how to get the object's information correspondent to the clicked line to put it in the form's fields.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Repetition - catalog</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>REPETITIONS.com</h1></header>
        <div id="app" class="float-container" style="height: 80%">
            <table class="catalog-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 200px">Corso</th>
                        <th style="width: 250px">Docente</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="rep in reps">
                            <td>{{rep.teacherName}} {{rep.teacherSurName}}</td>
                            <td>{{rep.course}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <form action="/Repetition/controller/ServletController" method="post" id="i">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="booking">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_t" value="rep.getId_teac"> <---set the value of the current row
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_c" value="rep.getId_cor"> <---set the value of the current row
                                    <button type="submit">Book</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <footer>xxxxxxx</footer>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var app = new Vue ({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    repetitions: [],
                    link: '/Repetition/ServletController?operation=catalog&device=x'
                },
                mounted(){
                    this.getRepetitions()
                },
                methods:{
                    getRepetitions: function(){
                        var self = this;
                        $.get(this.link, function(data) {
                            self.repetitions = data;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively the form request could be manage with another script, but there would be the same problem.

Comment: You should add information on how the data in your 'rep' is structured. Is it *nested* (`rep.course.id`), *flat* (`rep.courseId`), or do you have some other means to get the IDs you want (whatever `getId_teac` is supposed to do)?

Maybe it's as easy as using `v-bind:value` instead of `value`, but I can't know for sure.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's _flat_ like `rep.courseId`